# Add has many association with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I wonder if is possible to relations with the user model devise. For example, a user can have multiple phone numbers and addresses.

Regards

Comment: Yes, add has_many :addresses to user.rb file, then create the address model and add belongs_to :user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create different model to save detail information of the user if you have multiple phone numbers and addresses. Say information.rb is new model with its corresponding table as informations. 
In information.rb write
`belongs_to :user` and in user.rb write

```
has_many :informations
```

Hope this helps you.